# Where I can find a list of all the CategoryName and their CounterName for System.Diagnostics?

Tags: .net, system.diagnostics

This is my first question in this great site I've been using for a long time.

I would like to use System.Diagnostics to obtain from a remote computer the percentage of CPU and memory used. Also need to know the percentage of CPU and memory used by certain processes. To access the remote computer I implement "Impersonate".
This is easily done with WMI but is very inefficient and resource intensive for simple monitoring tasks.
In the CategoryName "Memory" with CounterName "Available MBytes" I can get how much memory is available but I have not found how to know the percentage of total memory used.

So...

Where I can find a list of all the CategoryName and their CounterName for System.Diagnostics?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need Performance Counters to get those remote computer statistics. Please visit this links to get more information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx
http://www.cinchoo.com/category/diagnostics/performancecounters

Comment: After spending an entire day searching I finally found it(conclusion: I'm really bad looking for)

In this link:
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fh4x1xb%28vs.71%29.aspx)

It is an excellent article entitled: "Walkthrough: Retrieving Categories and Counters"

Comment: @Deulis: i had visited the link provided by you. How could you get remote computer performance. it just list counters and categories from the local machine. how to get it for remote machine when it has domain name, user name, password?